# Updating a table with value sum of another table in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to update a sum(columne) from table1 to column from table2
I try to do this in sql like this:

```
UPDATE stock SET stock.chairout = (SELECT SUM(chairs_count) FROM Event
)
WHERE (([Event].[returned]))=False;
```

but it's giving me error like (it's not update able query)

can you guys help out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
UPDATE stock 
SET stock.chairout = 
(
  SELECT SUM(chairs_count) 
  FROM Event
)
WHERE Event.returned = False
```

Shouldn't your where clause be on the inside of the parenthesis, like so:

```
UPDATE stock 
SET stock.chairout = 
(
  SELECT SUM(chairs_count) 
  FROM Event
  WHERE Event.returned = False
)
```

Comment: Yeah right I put different one... even with this I get error of (operation must use updateblae query)